# Are the Google Cloud Endpoints only for REST?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

Are the Google Cloud Endpoints only for REST?

I have a virtual machine with cassandra, and now I need (temporarly) to expose this machine for the world (the idea is to run a cassandra client in some computers in my home/office/...). Is Google Cloud Endpoints the best way to expose this machine to world?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are running Cassandra on a Google Compute Engine (CE).  When one runs a compute engine, one can specify that one wants a public internet address to be associated with it.  This will allow an Internet connected client application to connect with it at that address.  The IP address can be declared as ephemeral (it can be changed by GCP over time) or it can be fixed (I believe there will be a modest charge for its allocation).  When one attempts to connect to the software running on the Compute Engine, a firewall rule (by default) will block the vast majority of incoming connections.  Fortunately, since you own the CE you also own the firewall configuration.  If we look here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureFireWall.html

we see the set of ports needed for different purposes. This gives us a hint as to what firewall rule changes to make.

Cloud Endpoints is for exposing APIs that YOU develop in your own applications and doesn't feel an appropriate component for accessing Cassandra.